# how do you reference a symbol in a different class in as3?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, class, import, symbols

I have created two separate classes and I want to use a symbol I created in the main class in a function I created in the second class. I have tried importing both classes into each other, however when I do this I get Error #1023. I am fairly new at as3 and any help is appreciated as I have no idea what I have done wrong.

-Thank you!

```html
public class SuspectSimulatorDesktop extends Sprite {
  [Embed(source="/../lib/SuspectSit.png")]
  private var CharacterSit:Class;
  var tools:Tools = new Tools();
  public var charSit:Bitmap = new CharacterSit();
  public function SuspectSimulatorDesktop() {
   
   addChild(tools);
  }
}
```

```js
//Tools (Second Class)
package com.powerflasher.SampleApp {
 import com.powerflasher.SampleApp.SuspectSimulatorDesktop;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 /**
  * @author timcis
  */
 
 public class Tools extends Sprite {
  [Embed(source="/../lib/Fist.png")]
  private var Fist:Class;
  var sSim:SuspectSimulatorDesktop = new SuspectSimulatorDesktop();
  private function punchChar(event:MouseEvent):void{
   sSim.charSit.rotation = 90;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error #1023 means that you have a stack overflow in your code. See this link for more explanations :

http://curtismorley.com/2007/08/19/flashflex-as3-error-1023-stack-overflow-occurred/

Regarding your code, you created a SuspectSimulatorDesktop class which instantiates a Tools object which instantiates itself a SuspectSimulatorDesktop object and so on... Each class calls the other one indefinitely and fills the stack, hence the stack overflow.

You need to break the circle by deleting either of these lines and adapt your code accordingly :

```
var tools:Tools = new Tools();
```

or

```
var sSim:SuspectSimulatorDesktop = new SuspectSimulatorDesktop();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix my problem!